# Deploying Oracle Service Bus With Maven: Deploys Fine From One Directory But Fails From Another

Tags: oracle, maven, servicebus, osb

I'm attempting to create an automated build and deployment for an OSB (Oracle Service Bus) composite. Such a system consists of two commands (run via command prompt from the directory in which the POM resides) after setting up Maven and the OSB plugin on the build server:

```
mvn package
mvn deploy -DoracleServerUrl=http://serverurl:port -DoraclUsername=username -DoraclePassword=password
```

This fails in the build system with the following exception:

```
The session cannot be activated due to the existence of conflicts.
```

But I believe, at it's core, this is because the build system creates the package with the first command during the build phase, and then deploys with the second command during the release phase.

If I take the code directly and run the two commands from the directory 1:
    D:\OSBComposites\HelloWorldOSBService\HelloWorldOSBService
the commands run and the composite deploys fine.

If I literally copy the same code from Directory 1 to Directory 2 and run the same commands from directory 2:
    D:\OSBComposites\HelloWorldOSBService\HelloWorldOSBService2
the second command fails with the same exception cited above.

This isn't a one-off situation either - I can recreate it dozens of times consistently. Running the commands from Directory 1 always succeeds while running the commands from Directory 2 always fails with the exception noted above.

And yes, this is a simple default HelloWorld composite - as simple as can be with no references to absolute paths.

Is there a cache in Maven or OSB that's "remembering" the original path from which the composite was first deployed or some other mechanism that prevents a composite from being deployed from a different location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `pom.xml` resides in `/path/directory1/pom.xml` , your OSB project would get deployed as `directory1` - redeploying as directory2 could then cause conflicts that you observe. 
If you need to deploy it from a different location, you could place it in `/path2/directory1/pom.xml`

For your example, this should work:
Copy your project's content to the path similar to below and then run the maven deployment

```
D:\OSBComposites\HelloWorldOSBService2\HelloWorldOSBService
```

Comment: That was it, thank you.

For anyone else trying to integrate these into a TFS build system, there are a few things to watch out for.

Source is always compiled from a directory named "S". If your build steps involved deployment to a server from the build itself (which is a terrible practice I don't recommend) You'll need to put your artifacts into a subfolder with the desired name.

Releases are performed from a directory that matches the "Artifact Name" value from the Publish Artifact step in your build. Enter the desired directory name there.

Comment: "deployment" in the maven world means pushing to an artifact repository (e.g. nexus). This is something that constantly happens for SNAPSHOT builds on a development build. The "deployment" to OSB runtime happens in the pre-integration-testing step and again, is desirable if it happens constantly on SNAPSHOT builds on a DEV environment, accompanied by unit tests. For "higher" environments, you can promote your tested, versioned, non-SNAPSHOT builds from the artifact repository - your CI server can have separate build jobs for "promotion" to test/uat/live